# Replace / Update Score in HTML Canvas Game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I want the score(s) to update as they increment with continuous wins/fails.

I know `.append()` is only meant to append objects to the page. But I can't figure out how to replace the content with the new score, instead of continuously appending new strings.

I've tried `.replace()`  `.replaceWith()` `.replaceAll()`; setting the new score to another variable and writing a conditional statement. I feel like I'm looking over something ridiculously obvious, but can't figure it out. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Any input is appreciated. Thank you!

```
var Player = function() {

    this.xRange = [-2, 402];
    this.yRange = [-20, 380];
    this.sprite = 'images/char-boy.png';
    this.wins = 0;
    this.fails = 0;
    this.reset();
};


Player.prototype.update = function() {

    if (this.y <= 20) {
        // player is on water, reset
        this.wins++;
        $("#wins").append("Wins: " + this.wins);
        this.reset();
    } else if (this.y <= 220 & this.x >= 0) {
        var charBoy = this;
        // player is on road rows, check collisions
        // loop through each bug
        allEnemies.forEach(function(enemy) {
            // is the bug on the same row as the player?
            if (enemy.y == charBoy.y) {
                // is the bug on the player?
                if (enemy.x >= charBoy.x - 30 && enemy.x <= charBoy.x + 30) {
                    charBoy.fails++;
                    $("#fails").append("Fails: " + charBoy.fails);
                    charBoy.reset();
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're replacing the element's contents with text only, you can use [`.text`](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text2):

```
$("#fails").text("Fails: " + charBoy.fails);
```

If you want to replace the contents with html, you can use [`.html`](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html2)

```
$("#fails").html("Fails: " + charBoy.fails);
```